# How to get server side datetime using Caml query?

Tags: sharepoint-server, caml-query

Using caml query I get Calender Events but Time will be changes..How to get server Time zone ..This return time +5.30 hrs.

```
  CamlQuery camlQuery = new CamlQuery();
            camlQuery.ViewXml = "<View><Query><Where>" +
                              "<DateRangesOverlap><FieldRef Name=\"EventDate\" />" +
                              "<FieldRef Name=\"EndDate\" />" +
                              "<FieldRef Name=\"RecurrenceID\"/>" +
                              "<Value Type=\"DateTime\"><Month /></Value></DateRangesOverlap>" +
                              "</Where></Query></View>";

  ListItemCollection collListItem = oList.GetItems(camlQuery);

            clientContext.Load(collListItem);


            clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
  foreach (ListItem oListItem in collListItem)
            {

                var Title = oListItem["Title"] != null ? oListItem["Title"].ToString() : "";
                var EventDate = oListItem["EventDate"] != null ? oListItem["EventDate"].ToString() : "";
                var EndDate = oListItem["EndDate"] != null ? oListItem["EndDate"].ToString() : "";
                var Location = oListItem["Location"] != null ? oListItem["Location"].ToString() : "";
                var Description = oListItem["Description"] != null ? oListItem["Description"].ToString() : "";

  Calender item = new Calender();

                item.Title = Title;
                item.EventDate = Convert.ToDateTime(EventDate);
                item.EndDate =Convert.ToDateTime(EndDate);
                item.Location = Location;
                item.Description = Description;


                Result.Add(item);
}
```

In Calender It display date as:means start Time is 3PM to 4PM 
[image]

but it return as:
[image]

Comment: what is the CAML query you are using ?

Comment: I add caml query please check it..

Comment: Thanks, are you binding the results to html somewhat as  `new Date(item.EventDate)` ?

Comment: actually I have use it in C#...I bind this to DateTime object

Comment: can you also add that code in the question ?

Comment: can you try it as  :

`item.EndDate = Convert.ToDateTime(EndDate);

System.TimeZoneInfo utcZone = System.TimeZoneInfo.Utc;

item.EndDate = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(item.EndDate, utcZone);` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try the below line.

```
 item.EventDate = TimeZone.CurrentTimeZone.ToLocalTime(EventDate);
```

Answer (score 1):

I had seen many a times people are struggling with `DateTime` field in SharePoint. SharePoint internally store DateTime filed into UTC format.

So to solve your problem you need to convert the UTC time in accordance with your sever time zone. You can get the web time zone using `SPWeb` object. Following is the property you need to use.

```
SPWeb.RegionalSettings.TimeZone
```

Also if you are using CSOM C# then you need to refer to `Web` object instead of `SPWeb`.

Comment: Not able to use SPWeb object..I only worked using Client context object.

Comment: You can use `ClientContent.Current.Web` object to get `RegionalSettings.TimeZone` property.

Comment: Also i was trying out something with SP page JS global variable and found you can extract web application time zone using JS on page as well using `_spPageContextInfo.webTimeZoneData` property.